# Scheme - Recursive cases

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm finishing up a Scheme assignment and I'm having some trouble with the recursive cases for two functions.

The first function is a *running-sums* function which takes in a list and returns a list of the running sums i.e `(summer '(1 2 3)) ---> (1 3 6)` Now I believe I'm very close but can't quite figure out how to fix my case. Currently I have

```
    (define (summer L)
      (cond ((null? L) '())
        ((null? (cdr L)) '())
        (else (cons (car L) (+ (car L) (cadr L))))))
```

I know I need to recursively call `summer`, but I'm confused on how to put the recursive call in there.

Secondly, I'm writing a function which counts the occurrences  of an element in a list. This function works fine through using a helper function but it creates duplicate pairs.

```
(define (counts L)
  (cond ((null? L) '())
        (else (cons (cons (car L) (countEle L (car L))) (counts (cdr L))))))

(define (countEle L x)
   (if (null? L) 0
       (if (eq? x (car L)) (+ 1 (countEle (cdr L) x)) (countEle (cdr L) x))))
```

The expected output is:

```
(counts '(a b c c b b)) --> '((a 1) (b 3) ( c 2))
```

But it's currently returning `'((a . 1) (b . 3) (c . 2) (c . 1) (b . 2) (b . 1))`. So it's close; I'm just not sure how to handle checking if I've already counted the element.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you expect the output of the second procedure to be?

Comment: Sure! (counts '(a b c c b b)) --> '((a 1) (b 3) ( c 2)) But its currently returning '((a . 1) (b . 3) (c . 2) (c . 1) (b . 2) (b . 1)). So its close I'm just not sure how to handle checking if Ive already counted an element

Comment: you shouldn't ask two different questions at once. each question should be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

To have a running sum, you need in some way to keep track of *the last sum*. So some procedure should have two arguments: the rest of the list to sum (which may be the whole list) and the sum so far.

```
(define (running-sum L)
  (define (rs l s)
    ...)
  (rs L 0))
```

For the second procedure you want to do something like

```
(define (count-elems L)
  (define (remove-elem e L) ...)
  (define (count-single e L) ...)
  (if (null? L)
      '()
      (let ((this-element (car L)))
        (cons (list this-element (count-single this-element L))
              (count-elems (remove-elem this-element (cdr L)))))))
```

Be sure to remove the elements you've counted before continuing! I think you can fill in the rest.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the count-elems procedure. So are you saying I could them element, then remove the element from the list before recursively passing the list back in?

Comment: Yes, once you've counted the occurences of `b`s in the list, we want to remove them before continuing so they aren't counted again.

Answer (score 0):

To your first problem:

The mistake in your procedure is, that there is no recursive call of "summer". Have a look at the last line.

```
(else (cons (car L) (+ (car L) (cadr L))))))
```

Here is the complete solution:

```
(define (summer LL)

  (define (loop sum LL)
    (if (null? LL)
      '()
      (cons (+ sum (car LL)) (loop (+ sum (car ll)) (cdr LL)))))

  (loop 0 LL))
```